# Frequent login failure on Yahoo Mail from GMail app

Tags: gmail, yahoo-mail

I have added my Yahoo Mail account to Gmail app on my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy Note 3, latest Gmail version)

However, ~5 times out of 6, the app fails to log in to Yahoo (the username/pwd and other settings are clearly correct since it **does** succeed in connecting once in a while).

Server is android.smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port 465. SSL/TLS security

Error is "Username or password is incorrect".

What could be causing this and what can I do to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. I didn't find a solution yet, but I'd like share my opinion on the possible cause of this issue.

After I re-try the sign-in, the sign-in page shows an error indicating redirection loop or proxy loop error.

Sometimes, I get error message saying that I'm trying to login from an unexpected country, and I have to verify the log-in with a SMS message.

Some other cases, if I login the www.yahoo.com with the browser, with password and CAPTCHA, on the same connection, I re-try the login in gmail app, it works.

Most of the time, in the gmail app, when I re-try the log-in, I just get a dumb error message that leaves no clue.

My theory is that the yahoo server does a lousy job when it tries to balance between the user convenience and security. The server is too sensitive to "suspicious" login attempt, and didn't have a better way to offer CAPTCHA validation with the gmail login.

Answer (score 1):

Remove *Yahoo* account from device and manually add it later.
In Manual Setup, Port *443* will be assigned  and
Server is set-up with *android.smtp.mail.yahoo.com* and Security type as *SSL/TLS*

Answer (score -1):

Gmail used to logged in to Yahoo using regular IMAP, but recently it was changed to Yahoo authentication which failed frequently.

The solution is to find a copy of the Gmail 5.1 APK, install it,  and setup your Yahoo mail. This version allows you to setup regular Yahoo IMAP.

After that,  you can upgrade to a more recent Gmail version.

Comment: You can just add it manually as IMAP instead to get the same effect.

Comment: No point in manually installing old APKs and stuff from iffy sources.